# Why I can't use global float constants in device code?

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

When I try to compile following C++ code in VS 2010:

```
float const x = 1.0;

__global__ void kernel()
{
    int a = x;
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

I get the following error:

> identifier "x" is undefined in device code

Everything was fine when I compiled the code in GCC.

Is there a way to use float constant in device code in VS without resorting to `#define`?

Comment: Is this the *actual* code that generates the error? I can't reproduce it on any platform I have access to.

Comment: Yes, this is the whole content of the kernel.cu file that i'm compiling using VS 2010 with Parallel Nsight. (created new `CUDA 4.2 Runtime` project for this). I am working on 64-bit Windows 7.